# myisampack no access to data files

Tags: mysql, myisam

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on AWS.

Using ubuntu logon under /home/ubuntu/dev.

Created database myFiles.

Added MYISAM table with static data and tried....

```
myisampack /var/lib/mysql/myFiles/table01.MYI
```

and this failed with :

var/lib/mysql/myFiles/table01.MYI gave error 13 on open

permissions are :

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 2340864 Nov 15 00:25 table01.MYI
```

parent folders :

```
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 Nov 15 00:25  myFiles 
.. and ..
drwx------  7 mysql     mysql     4096 Nov 15 00:05 mysql
```

so I lose permissions at /var/lib/mysql

What is the canonical way to perform this?

I have tried adding ubuntu to the mysql group (group has read at least, and execute on the folders).

Running as sudo gives a "140" (Wrong create options).

I have tried running from the /opt folder.

I know this may be an obscure usage, but I am hoping someone has had had to sweat over this already.

I don't want to chmod the tree as the permissions are probably carefully considered.

Comment: Note that I am troubleshooting an historical script that "no longer works out of the box"  so this did work in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

```
$ sudo myisampack /var/lib/mysql/myFiles/table01.MYI
```

Plan B:

```
$ su mysql myisampack /var/lib/mysql/myFiles/table01.MYI
```

Plan C:

Don't use MyISAM; then you won't need myisampack.  Use InnoDB.

Plan D:

Run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` while connected to the server.

C is the preferred approach.

Comment: Upvoting. Looking next door the filemode should probably be 774, so I need to look at the root cause for getting 640.  I am forcing them to 774 and leaving them there. sudo for the pack, not needed for the check.  We save space and get de facto RO out of this static data with packed myisam, yes we will consider innoDB.

Comment: @mckenzm - 755 for directories -- that gives read and search (the "x" part) for all.  644 for files if you are not  owner or in the same "group" and only need read perm.

Comment: I chose it because that is what the neighbouring databases were using.  I have gone back to inspect an old package install of "mantis" and that has a mix of 660 and 640 and seems to be MyISAM centric.  I have a feeling I we are just going to move these to InnoDB and restrict access and to heck with space.

Comment: Yes, convert.  Typically InnoDB takes 2x-3x the space.